# Can't print through business printer

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I am having problems printing to the printer connected to my (SBS2003) business's network. The Printer is a Sharp MX-M314N. All Windows computers on the network can print to it fine, just my ubuntu machine that won't.

I know the IP of the printer and I can ping it and even print files from it by going to 192.168.0.50 in firefox and uploading a file.

If I do an `nmap` on the IP of the printer and the server I get this:

```
jamesmaddison@development:~$ nmap 192.168.0.50

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-11 16:12 BST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.50
Host is up (0.46s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
23/tcp    open  telnet
80/tcp    open  http
443/tcp   open  https
515/tcp   open  printer
631/tcp   open  ipp
5900/tcp  open  vnc
9100/tcp  open  jetdirect
50001/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.55 seconds

jamesmaddison@development:~$ nmap mastermagnets

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-11 16:35 BST
Nmap scan report for mastermagnets (192.168.0.2)
Host is up (0.00055s latency).
rDNS record for 192.168.0.2: mastermagnets.local
Not shown: 957 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
25/tcp    open  smtp
42/tcp    open  nameserver
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
88/tcp    open  kerberos-sec
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
389/tcp   open  ldap
443/tcp   open  https
444/tcp   open  snpp
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
464/tcp   open  kpasswd5
593/tcp   open  http-rpc-epmap
636/tcp   open  ldapssl
691/tcp   open  resvc
1025/tcp  open  NFS-or-IIS
1027/tcp  open  IIS
1042/tcp  open  unknown
1045/tcp  open  unknown
1046/tcp  open  unknown
1048/tcp  open  unknown
1049/tcp  open  unknown
1054/tcp  open  unknown
1081/tcp  open  unknown
1087/tcp  open  unknown
1094/tcp  open  unknown
1104/tcp  open  unknown
2301/tcp  open  compaqdiag
2381/tcp  open  unknown
3268/tcp  open  globalcatLDAP
3269/tcp  open  globalcatLDAPssl
3389/tcp  open  ms-term-serv
5633/tcp  open  unknown
6001/tcp  open  X11:1
6002/tcp  open  X11:2
6004/tcp  open  X11:4
6101/tcp  open  backupexec
6106/tcp  open  isdninfo
8080/tcp  open  http-proxy
8081/tcp  open  blackice-icecap
8082/tcp  open  blackice-alerts
8443/tcp  open  https-alt
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.18 seconds
```

And when I do a 'smbclient' I get the following:

```
~$ smbclient -U MASTERMAGNETS/JamesMaddison -L //SBSSRV

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
Line100         Disk      
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
C$              Disk      Default share
S$              Disk      Default share
Technical       Disk      
IRS             Disk      
Designjet 500-24 Printer   HP Designjet 500 24 by HP
Accounts        Disk      
RICOH           Printer   RICOH Aficio 1027
clients         Disk      Windows Small Business Server Client Setup
tsclient        Disk      
IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
Resources$      Disk      "Event logging files"
FxsSrvCp$       Disk      Common Fax Cover Pages Folder
tsweb           Disk      
SHARP MX-M314N  Printer   192.168.0.50
ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
faxclient       Disk      Microsoft Shared Fax Clients
ClientApps      Disk      Windows Small Business Server Client Applications
DLOAgent        Disk      Symantec DLO Share
Magnets-database files Disk      
Magnet-database files Disk      
D$              Disk      Default share
Users           Disk      Users Shared Folders
Public          Disk      
actsql          Disk      
SYSVOL          Disk      Logon server share
Address         Disk      "Access to address objects"
Confidential    Disk      
NETLOGON        Disk      Logon server share
SBSSRV.LOG      Disk      Exchange message tracking logs

Server               Comment
---------            -------
ANDY                
DESIGN1              
DESIGN2              
DESIGN3              
DEVELOPMENT          development server (Samba, Linux)
FRANK                
JOE                  
JONATHAN            
KIM                  Kim
ORDERPRINT           Purchase Order Printer
PHIL                
SBSSRV              
TERMSRV              

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
MASTERMAGNETS        SBSSRV
```

I have tried the following protocols in CUPS:

```
smb://MASTERMAGNETS/SBSSRV/Sharp%20MX-M314N/
smb://jamesmaddison:password@MASTERMAGNETS/SBSSRV/Sharp%20MX-M314N/
socket://192.168.0.50:9100
ipp://192.168.0.50/ipp?version=1.0
lpd://192.168.0.50/lp
```

and all of the "Discovered Printers" that CUPS lists. (They're dnssd protocols)

I have also tried adding the printer through `lpadmin`:

```
jamesmaddison@development:~$ lpadmin -p SharpPrinter -v smb://jamesmaddison:password@MASTERMAGNETS/SBSSRV/Sharp%20MX-M314N/ -P /usr/share/cups/model/sharp/en/Sharp_MX-M314N.ppd
```

`smbstatus` always reports no processes (I just get table headers). I don't know if that's important but it seems suspicious to me.

The `[printers]` section of my `smb.conf` is pretty much the default:

```
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
```

Here's what the CUPS error log says for the last job I tried.

```
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAcceptClient: 17 from localhost (Domain)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 CUPS-Get-Default 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] CUPS-Get-Default
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Default (no URI) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Active clients"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST /printers/Sharp_MX-M314N HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients", busy="Not busy"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 Create-Job 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Create-Job ipp://localhost:631/printers/Sharp_MX-M314N
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] add_job: requesting-user-name="root"
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Adding start banner page "none".
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Notifier dbus started - PID = 4290
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(-----S)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Queued on "Sharp_MX-M314N" by "root".
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for Create-Job (ipp://localhost:631/printers/Sharp_MX-M314N) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST /printers/Sharp_MX-M314N HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 Send-Document 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Send-Document ipp://localhost:631/printers/Sharp_MX-M314N
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdIsAuthorized: requesting-user-name="root"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Auto-typing file...
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Request file type is text/plain.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] File of type text/plain queued by "root".
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Adding end banner page "none".
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(-----S)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] job-sheets=none,none
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[0]="Sharp_MX-M314N"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[1]="67"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[2]="root"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[3]="test.txt"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[4]="1"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[5]="finishings=3 number-up=1 job-uuid=urn:uuid:c5ced1ef-681f-39c9-6851-d89d94bae8c9 job-originating-host-name=localhost time-at-creation=1373875872 time-at-processing=1373875872"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00067-001"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@development"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/1.5.3"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[14]="CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[15]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[16]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[17]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[18]="LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[19]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Sharp_MX-M314N.ppd"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[20]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[21]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[22]="DEVICE_URI=smb://SBSSRV/SHARP%20MX-M314N"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[23]="PRINTER_INFO=Sharp_MX-M314N"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[24]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[25]="PRINTER=Sharp_MX-M314N"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[26]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[27]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[28]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-postscript"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] envp[29]="AUTH_I****"
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf (PID 4291)
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 4292)
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops (PID 4293)
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/smb (PID 4294)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(-----S)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/Sharp_MX-M314N) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] Connected to D-BUS
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdCloseClient: 17
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] pdftops - copying to temp print file "/tmp/010c551e5ab02"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Page = 595x842; 12,12 to 583,830
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Connected with username/password...
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] PID 4291 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf) exited with no errors.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] PID 4292 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Using image rendering resolution 300 dpi
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Started filter pdftops (PID 4295)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Started filter pstops (PID 4296)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Page = 595x842; 12,12 to 583,830
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] slow_collate=0, slow_duplex=0, slow_order=0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Before copy_comments - %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %!PS-Adobe-3.0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %Produced by poppler pdftops version: 0.18.4 (http://poppler.freedesktop.org)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %%LanguageLevel: 2
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %%DocumentMedia: plain 595 842 0 () ()
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %%Pages: 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] %%EndComments
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Before copy_prolog - %%BeginDefaults
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Before copy_setup - %%BeginSetup
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] PID 4295 (pdftops) exited with no errors.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Before page loop - %%Page: 1 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Copying page 1...
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] PAGE: 1 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(-----S)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] pagew = 571.0, pagel = 818.0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] bboxx = 0, bboxy = 0, bboxw = 595, bboxl = 842
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] PageLeft = 12.0, PageRight = 583.0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] PageTop = 830.0, PageBottom = 12.0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] PageWidth = 595.0, PageLength = 842.0
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Wrote 1 pages...
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] PID 4296 (pstops) exited with no errors.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] PID 4293 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops) exited with no errors.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] PID 4294 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/smb) exited with no errors.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(-----S)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
I [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Job 67] Job completed.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(----J-)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(-----S)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] [Notifier] state=3
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAcceptClient: 17 from localhost (Domain)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 Get-Notifications 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Get-Notifications /
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdIsAuthorized: requesting-user-name="jamesmaddison"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Notifications (/) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 WAITING Closing on EOF
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdCloseClient: 17
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAcceptClient: 17 from localhost (Domain)
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 CUPS-Get-Printers 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] CUPS-Get-Printers
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Printers (no URI) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 CUPS-Get-Classes 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] CUPS-Get-Classes
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Classes (no URI) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 POST / HTTP/1.1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdAuthorize: No authentication data provided.
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdReadClient: 17 1.1 CUPS-Get-Default 1
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] CUPS-Get-Default
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Default (no URI) from localhost
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:12 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [15/Jul/2013:09:11:13 +0100] [Job 67] Unloading...
```

Here's the result of `snmp` with `CUPS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` http://pastebin.com/CarHtA9q

And I often get a notification saying "Printer Error: printer error Printer Name: `connecting-to-device`"

I just can't get it to work, the problem seems to be between Cups and the windows server as if I go to 192.168.0.50:9100 in firefox the printer prints the GET header it receives. I can also go to 192.168.0.50 and upload a file directly to the printer. Lastly I can ftp into the printer and upload files that way.

---

As requested `lpstat -d` and `lpstat -t`

```
jamesmaddison@development:~$ lpstat -d
system default destination: Sharp-MX-M314N

jamesmaddison@development:~$ lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: Sharp-MX-M314N
device for Sharp-MX-M314N: smb://MASTERMAGNETS/SBSSRV/SHARP%20MX-M314N
Sharp-MX-M314N accepting requests since Mon 15 Jul 2013 13:30:20 BST
printer Sharp-MX-M314N is idle.  enabled since Mon 15 Jul 2013 13:30:20 BST
```

Comment: As far as I can see, your CUPS log only lists web config events like accessing the CUPS configuration page (marked with `CGI`). Could you try to post the logs **while not using the web interface**?

Comment: @gertvdijk I've updated the log

Comment: It's a lot of output and it shows a lot more actions than just sending a job. For example I see `Calling DeleteDevice(cups-Sharp_MX-M314N)`. So please explain what you're doing in there and please try to keep a minimum of log lines appearing around the time you encounter your issue.

Comment: @gertvdijk I'm not sure why that's showing up. All I did was open `system-config-printer` and selected the printer and pressed `Print Test Page` and copied the output from today as this was the first thing I did.

Comment: @gertvdijk Okay I've updated the log again, I turned the log level down a notch and did `sudo lp test.txt`. Sorry for messing you around.

Comment: There are many discussions of Sharp printers in linux on the net, and most end unsolved. I am afraid there are no usable drivers for Sharp. Still, you can proxy you printing through any Windows machine.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino How would I go about that? Is there a good tutorial anywhere?

Comment: There are applications for Window$ that automatically print all files that are put into specified folder. And there is Samba. That's what I meant.

Comment: Ensure the business printer is powered on and connected to the network or computer. Verify that the correct printer is selected in your print settings on the computer. Check for any error messages on the printer display and resolve any issues indicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set "create mask" to 0775 - also :

> create mask = 0775

0700 would mean here - only admin may print - am not sure how you tried to print - from home over phone-line at firm as admin ?

Comment: Do you need permission to print to this printer? (like a secured network resource) is the networking interface of the printer open? can you view what the printer is doing when your job gets denied? Is this a shared" pritner like a usb printer on an windows machine, vs an actual networked printer? Hows your firewall doing? is your firewall blocking traffic?
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-samba-to-communicate-with-other-windowslinux-systems/

nmap tells me that both UNIX LPD (port 515) and JetDirect (aka IPP) port 9100 are unsupported.  Can you change that?

Comment: @j0h It's an actual network printer. There's no internal firewall.

Comment: oh weird, i must have miss-read that, I thought ports 9100, and 515 were not open. can we see lpstat -d and lpstat -t ?

Comment: incidentally, are you running Ubuntu server? Why are you trying to use samba as opposed to IPP? have you tried assigning the printer a generic driver, or are you using the OEM driver http://tinyurl.com/nbg2qnb

Comment: @j0h I'm using the OEM driver. I have tried both Samba and IPP, neither work.

Comment: @j0h I have added the results of `lpstat -d` and `lpstat -t` at the bottom of my main post.

Comment: In lpstat -t, I am noticing the difference between "Sharp-MX-M314N" and "Sharp MX-M314N" in the network location. Perhaps there is something going on with how the device is named?

Maybe look at the samba logs... Ive been on vaction last week, sorry about the delay.